# Bootstrap, how make a navbar sticky after scrolling down when using viewport height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get this effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/ux41b606/

but with use no px but viewport height. I tried but I don't know how to set `jQuery` if to viewport height.

Here my jsfidlle:

http://jsfiddle.net/80nyn8bh/2/

How can I fix that and get sticky navbar when browser srolling more than 100% viewport ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Make your jsfiddle's a link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I find the answer. I fix this by one line `if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height())` and it's working good.